# Spring do not update session for ajax polling

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc, session-timeout

We are currently running into a problem with session time outs on one of our Spring web applications. The session never times out because we have a continuous ajax request polling the server. Is there a way to tell spring to ignore this request and not update the session so that time out works as expected?

Comment: Can you let me know if you used SessionRegistry to ignore long-polling urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a timer, equal to your session timeout, along side the continuous ajax request that would log the user out if the page never refreshes. Another idea would be to host the URL that you are hitting in a separate web application on the same domain. I'm not sure if Spring has something built in for what you are doing.

I thought about this some more. You could implement your own session registry that ignores the Ajax URLs. Basically you wouldn't set the last accessed time for a user in the session registry if the URL matched one that you defined in your ignore list or filter defined in the Spring Security filter chain.

See [SessionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html)