# Heartbeat and session timout

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, spring-security, session-timeout

I'm currently using Spring Boot for an application. There I use pessimistic locking to prevent other users from editing the same data.
The lock is updated every x seconds as long as the user is on the page. 
However the ajax calls renew the session so that it does not time out. 
Is there a way to exempt those calls from session renewal? I couldn't find any clues on how to do it and would appreciate a hint in the right direction.

I work with the newest version of spring boot and spring security.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298968/spring-do-not-update-session-for-ajax-polling